# Installing a swing set between two brick walls?

Tags: walls, load-bearing, play-structures

My neighbors and I are considering putting up a swing set in the alleyway between our houses. The space is about 10' wide, and the house walls on both sides are brick (about 4" thick).

Which of the following alternatives would be best, if we wanted to have two swings there, each capable of holding a child up to 80 lb. or so?

1. Put up brackets on both walls to hold the pole.
2. Drill holes in both facing walls, put in the pole, fill the holes with concrete.
3. Forget about attaching to the walls; get a freestanding swing set and attach it to the ground.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## 3 for two reasons:

1. Your walls are not meant for dynamic, changing loads such as those caused by swingset motions, so you don't know the potential damage long term; and
2. I would hesitate very much to buy a house which had a physical connection to another person's house via a toy.

Comment: Reason 3: The kids grow up and then you'll be left with a pole stuck in your wall.